# Centering div element

Tags: html, centering

How can I center the description in the main block?
I tried to use `{margin: auto}` or `{margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto}`, but it does not helps.

```html
<main class="row">
  <div class="description">A little description</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Add `text-align:center;`

Comment: Refer this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
.description {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content:    
}
```

Comment: justify-content needs some kind of value, was this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the description-<div> to be inline-block, otherwise it will stay there. Try it with this entry in your stylesheet:

```
.description {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 then use mx auto.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<main class="row">
  <div class="description mx-auto">A little description</div>
</main>
</body>
```

Otherwise

```css
.description {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <main class="row">
      <div class="description">A little description</div>
    </main>
```